# Comparing Strings Character by Character and printing both the string As mentioned at the end of program

Tags: java

```
package com.stringrelatedfunction;

public class StringTaskOnComparisson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Reading two Strings as input */
        String one = "Vikram is doing a task of which a programming on Strings";
        String two = "Vikram is doing a task of which a programming is Arrays of jjjj";

        /* Taking third string as empty String */
        String three = " ";

        /* Printing the length of both the strings */
        System.out.println(one.length());
        System.out.println(two.length());

        /* Comparing two strings using equals method */
        if (one.equals(two)) {
            System.out.println("both are same");
        }

        /* Else checking length of String One is Greater than String two */
        else {
            if (one.length() > two.length()) {

                /*
                 * If yes then appending String three which is empty string in
                 * String two such that both the string length becomes equal
                 */
                for (int i = 0; i < one.length() - 1; i++) {
                    if (one.charAt(i) != two.charAt(i)) {
                        two += three;
                    }

                }
            }

            /* Similar to the above condition here if one is smaller than two */
            else if (one.length() < two.length()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < two.length() - 1; i++) {
                    if (two.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                        one += three;
                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println(one.length());
            System.out.println(two.length());

            /* Converting String into char array to compare each character */
            char[] oneChar = one.toCharArray();
            char[] twoChar = two.toCharArray();
            System.out.println("non similar words are");

            /*
             * Comparing Strings character by character and printing the
             * dis-similar ones
             */
            if (one.length() > two.length()) {
                System.out.print("{");
                for (int i = 0; i <= one.length() - 1; i++) {
                    if (oneChar[i] != twoChar[i]) {
                        System.out.print(twoChar[i]);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("}");
            } else if (one.length() < two.length()) {
                System.out.print("{");
                for (int i = 0; i <= two.length() - 1; i++) {
                    if (twoChar[i] != oneChar[i]) {
                        System.out.print(oneChar[i]);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i want to print the ouput as :Vikram is doing a task of which a programming [on Strings] {is Arrays of jjjj} So that the dis-similar words are separated from the Similar Once For example just see this site as how it compares two string of words: textdiff.com

Comment: Some spell checking and a little more explanatory text would probably fit that question well. As it is I have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: ya i will rectify it as i could not post my question properly this time..

Comment: Please work at your question. Do you want to find out the indexes where the two words differ?

Comment: i want to print the ouput as :Vikram is doing a task of which a programming [on Strings] {is Arrays of jjjj} So that the dis-similar words are seperated from the Similar Once For example just see this site as how it compares two string of words: textdiff.com – Vikram Singh

Comment: I join others in saying that the question need improvement. You're talking about what you want in the output but not what you lack to get to it. Do you expect us to simply give you the entire code to do so ?

Comment: i have added comments in the program so that now one can understand that what i'm actually trying to do in it...

Comment: @VikramSingh I don't think the issue is that your code is difficult to understand. It's rather that your question is "Here's a bridge blueprint, I expect to build a house with it". You did not even ask a question.Nothing like "can someone explain to me how a bridge and a house are different?" or "How can I add a roof to my bridge to make it look like a house?" or even "How to draw a house blueprint?". I can easily see that your code won't get you to what you expect. But what do you want ? That I give you the code that does it ?

Comment: @Jeremy Grand well mam i got it as a task and using my brain i came up with the above program and it is giving me the output as {is Arrays of jjjj} so i'm getting output as Dissimillar words....but i was confused on how to get the expected output that why i posted my question here....And thanks for the suggestion you gave i will try it directly by comparing words rather than character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.stringrelatedfunction;

public class StringTaskOnComprassion2 {

    private String s1;
    private String s2;

    public StringTaskOnComprassion2(String s1, String s2) {
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "Same Different same differentAgain inSquareBraces  ";
        String s2 = " Same different   same   DifferentAgain     inFlowerBraces ";
        StringTaskOnComprassion2 sc = new StringTaskOnComprassion2(s1, s2);
        System.out.println(sc.compareString());
    }
    public String compareString() {
        s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();
        s2 = s2.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();
        String str1[] = s1.split(" ");
        String str2[] = s2.split(" ");
        String temp = "";

        int min = ((str1.length <= str2.length) ? (str1.length) : (str2.length));
        int max = ((str1.length >= str2.length) ? (str1.length) : (str2.length));

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (i < min) {
                temp += (str1[i].equals(str2[i]) ? (str1[i] + " ") : ("[" + str1[i] + "]" + " " + "{" + str2[i] + "}"+" "));
            } else if (max == str1.length) {
                temp += ("[" + str1[i] + "]" + " ");
            } else {
                temp += ("{" + str2[i] + "}" + " ");
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}



/*output:
Same [Different] {different} same [differentAgain] {DifferentAgain} [inSquareBraces] {inFlowerBraces} 
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.stringrelatedfunction;

public class StringTaskOnComparisson {

    private static String one;
    private static String two;


    public StringTaskOnComparisson(String one, String two) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }


    public static void comparingStrings() {
        one = one.replaceAll("\\s{2}", "");
        two = two.replaceAll("\\s{2}", "");
        one = one.trim();
        two = two.trim();
        System.out.println(one);
        System.out.println(two);
        String[] temp1 = one.split(" ");
        String[] temp2 = two.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < temp2.length; i++) {
            if (temp1[i].compareTo(temp2[i]) == 0) {
                System.out.print(" " + temp1[i]);
            }
            if (temp1[i].compareTo(temp2[i]) != 0) {
                System.out.print("[" + temp1[i] + "]");
            }
            if (temp2[i].compareTo(temp1[i]) != 0) {
                System.out.print("{" + temp2[i] + "}");
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringTaskOnComparisson stoc = new StringTaskOnComparisson("this is   my first program","  vikram is   my   name   ");
        StringTaskOnComparisson.comparingStrings();
    }
}
```

Output:

> this is my first program
>   vikram is my name
>   [this]{vikram} is my[first]{name}

Comment: How is that code handling temp1 and temp2 diffenrences in length ?

Comment: @JeremyGrand the new post covers all that is needed for the perfect output.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a list of string for both string input and compare each string on both list. If there is an element that doesn't match then do whatever to that string element. But before making the string input into a list, filter it first to a char array so that only words are added to the list and not punctuation and special characters.